# Combining Python Cement with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Looking for some pointers on how to combine the python cement framework (http://builtoncement.com/) with asyncio (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html).

I have an asyncio based event engine up and running and am pretty happy with the progress and simplicity. Decent performance as well.

Now I am in the need to add more complex handlers, hooks and plugins and browsing through the various options I found, cement seems to be a favorite and is also well maintained.

I like the fact that it deals with logging, config, arguments, output and plugins.

However I could not find a single example of using asyncio together with the cement framework.

Any points whether it is possible, advised and even alternatives to cement (that work well with asyncio) would be very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Cement is synchronous framework, sorry.
You can call `loop.run_forever()` in command handler though.

Comment: Too bad. Are there any frameworks out there for asyncio that deal with at least plugins? Need to extend my event engine with custom plugins that get loaded and activated from a plugin directory. Thank you!

Comment: Have been reading up on Cement and reached out to the lead developer. Looks like this will be a good match after all. Will report back on progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most parts it turns out to be very easy to integrate cement with asyncio. The best way I found is to extend CementApp with you own instance and leverage setup() to get the loop and register additional thread pools if needed.

registering a _post_run hook allows you to execute the run_until_complete of the init generator

while registering a _pre_close hook allows you to finish out all pending asyncio tasks.

An _init() and _finish() coroutine do the rest and the main app logic comes down to:

```
with myApp('myAppName') as app:
    app.run()
    app.log.info('Starting MyApp')

    try:
        app.run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit, CaughtSignal):
        app.log.info('Shutting down MyApp')

        app.close()
```

You can find a working example here: https://github.com/fxstein/SentientHome/blob/master/engine/event.engine.py

Comment: Since `CementApp.run_forever` wraps `CementApp.run`, why do you need to call them both?